# Salvando no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, json, slim

Preciso salvar um formulário no banco, com vários campos *input*. Alguém tem um exemplo de como faria para passar os campos. Estou usando o *framework* AngularJS (Se preciso transformar eles em um *array* ou usar json encode).
Está é a parte da *view* que contém o formulário. A dúvida é como envio `preco1` e `nome1` para o banco. O arquivo com os parametros e a configuração está Ok

```
<script>
        angular.module("slimApp", []);
        angular.module("slimApp").controller("slimAppController", function($scope, $http){
                $scope.app = "Slim Produtos";
                $scope.adicionarProduto = function(produtos){
                    $http.post('http://localhost/SlimProjeto/RestProdutos/produtos', {nome1:'', preco1:''}).
                      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      }).
                      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      });
                };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="slimAppController">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>{{app}}</h3>
        <form class="form-control" method="post" id="form">
            <input type="text" id="nome1" name="nome1"/>
            <input type="text" id="preco1" name="preco1"/>
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" ng-click="adicionarProduto(form)" >Adicionar Produto</button>
       </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: em vez de enviar cada item do objeto, envie o objeto inteiro.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82975/cadastro-de-dados-com-angularjs-e-php-n%C3%A3o-funciona/83162#83162

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
require '../Slim/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader(); $app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->response()->header('Content-Type',
'application/json;charset=utf-8');

$app->get('/', function () { echo "SlimProdutos"; });
$app->post('/produtos','addProduto');
$app->GET('/produto','adcProduto');

$app->run();

function getConn() { return new
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slimprodutos', 'root', '',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") ); }

function addProduto() { $request =
\Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request(); $produto =
json_decode($request->getBody()); $sql = "INSERT INTO produtos
(nome, preco, idCategoria) values (:nome, :preco, 1) "; $conn =
getConn(); $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("nome",$produto->nome);
$stmt->bindParam("preco",$produto->preco); $stmt->execute();
$produto->id = $conn->lastInsertId(); echo json_encode($produto); };
function adcProduto(){  echo('teste');   }
```

Answer (score -1):

No arquivo da sua rota do Slim:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post('/url_do_post', function () {

    // Pegue as variaveis 

    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = $request->getBody();


    // Função para conexão com banco

    function getConn()
    {
        return new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_banco',
            'usuario_banco',
            'senha_banco',
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
        );
    }

    // Para executar queries

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela SET coluna1=:valor1, coluna2=:valor2";
    $conn = getConn();
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam("coluna1", $data['valor1']);
    $query->bindParam("coluna2", $data['valor2']);
    $query->execute();
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: Funcionou de outro jeito. Segue abaixo o arquivo da rota, estava gerando uma query $produtos, e estava esquecendo de apenas chamas os atributos dela.