# Cadastro de dados com AngularJS e PHP não funciona

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Olá,

Tenho um formulário, simples, com 3 campos, nome, email e senha em HTML e junto com um código AngularJS.
Porém, ao submeter o formulário, recebo a mensagem de que o envio dos dados foram para o banco, mas eles não estão lá no mesmo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>CRUD AngularJS</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
<form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()">
Nome<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.nome"><br>
Email<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.email"><br>
Senha<br>
<input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.senha"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.list = [];
        var self = this;
        self.submit = function() {
          console.log('User clicked submit with ', self.user);
            $http.post('php/salvar.php', {'nome': $scope.nome, 'email': $scope.email, 'senha': $scope.senha})
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.status);
                console.log(response.data.msg);

              }, function(response) {
                console.log(response.status);
                console.log(response.msg);

              });
        }
}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
?php
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'angularDB';
$host = 'localhost';

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$nome = $_POST['nome']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$ins = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, '$nome', '$email', '$senha')");

if($ins == 1){
echo json_encode( array('status' => 200, 'msg' => 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!'));
}else{
echo json_encode( array('status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Erro ao cadastrar no banco.'));
}
?>
```

Comment: Oque ele retorna no response da requisição?

Comment: Por motivos de segurança, utilize prepared statements nas queries, principalmente as que envolvem strings, ajudando a eveitar SQL injection. Qual o valor da variável `$ins` após a query? O log de erro do PHP/Apache/Nginx possui alguma mensagem de erro? Tente habilitar exibição de erros para termos uma noção melhor do que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Ta bem simples e visivel o primeiro problema, funcionando ou não voce manda a mensagem de sucesso precisa tratar isso, caso contrario nunca saberá

Comment: Desculpe @Otto, como eu poderia tratar isso?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, eu não sei como usar prepared statement com mysqli.
Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @GustavoSevero da forma que esta na resposta

Comment: Bem @Otto, corrigi o tratamento. Coloquei na edição do post, veja lá.
E o que ocorre é que só é inserido no banco o código, ou seja, só o campo de código é preenchido, os demais campos ficam em branco... Muito estranho.

Comment: Pelo que já notei, o problema não é no php e sim no Angular.

Comment: Observe que no seu código o include do angular está quebrando.

Comment: Pronto @IvanFerrer, include corrigido.
Mas aqui no meu computador, não há essa quebra e mesmo assim, nada.

Comment: Ainda esta quebrado... rrsrsrs, faltou aspas

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se não ocorreu erros no PHP na hora da inserção:

exemplo:

```
if (mysqli_error($ins))
  echo json_encode( array('status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Ocorreu um problema'));
else
  echo json_encode( array('status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!'));
```

Comment: Uso esse seu código e rodo apenas o php na url, @CleberAzevedo?

Comment: Bom, rodei só o php na url, como eu te perguntei e a mensagem que apareceu na tela foi essa, @CleberAzevedo.
"{"status":1,"msg":"Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!"}"

Comment: @GustavoSevero, esse método `$http.post({...})` o correto não seria `$http({...})` ? você pode usar um equivalente: `jQuery.post({...})`ou `$.post({...})`. Só não esquece de inserir a biblioteca jquery.

Comment: Então o problema não esta na inserção com o php, tem certeza que esta passando os parâmetros do ng corretamente?

Comment: Você usou o mysqli_error($ins) ? Ele vai te retornar se houve erro na query do PHP

Comment: @IvanFerrer, tenho certeza que não pois na na documentação do Angular mostra assim como coloquei. Veja no link:
[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http]

Comment: Ah, ok, eu não tinha certeza sobre isso, mas a saída não teria que ser algo assim: `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$putData); ` é que eu estou mais acostumado em definir o post como valor do objeto:`$http({
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      url: 'url.php', method: 'POST', data: $.param({param: param}) });`

Comment: Aqui tem uma explicação do problema do uso de `$http.post()`, tá em inglês, mas acho que dá pra entender: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Comment: @IvanFerrer, você tem mais alguma dica, sugestão?

Comment: Vou tentar te dar uma resposta, mas não vou testar, você me diz se funcionou blz.

Answer (score 1):

Como você usa o ng-submit sobre um local específico você pode reaproveitar e resumir o código até mesmo nos ng-model, vou passar meu jeito de criar `<form>` com `ng-submit` com angular baseado no que precisa:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>CRUD AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
        Nome<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="nome"><br>
        Email<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="email"><br>
        Senha<br>
            <input type="password" ng-model="senha"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var Myapp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

Myapp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function () {

        var formData = { 'nome' : $scope.nome, 'email' : $scope.email, 'senha' : $scope.senha };
        var postData = 'myData='+JSON.stringify(formData);

        var request = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: './php/salvar.php',
            data: postData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
        });

        request.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.success = true;
            console.log(status + ' - ' + data); //Captura de Dados
            if ( data.trim() === '[Protocolo] = #1') {
              alert("[INFO]: Cadastro efetuado com sucesso! ");
            }
            if ( data.trim() === '[Protocolo] = #2') {
              alert("[INFO]: Erro ao cadastrar no banco. ");
            }
        });
        request.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.error = true;
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}]);
```

PHP

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'angularDB';
$host = 'localhost';

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8');

    include("../class/conexao.class.php");

    $myData = json_decode($_POST['myData'], true);

$nome = $myData['nome'];
$email = $myData['email'];
$senha = $myData['senha'];

$ins = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, '$nome', '$email', '$senha')");

if($ins == 1) {
    echo ("[Protocolo] = #1");
} else {
    echo ("[Protocolo] = #2");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro temos a HTML com angular:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <title>CRUD AngularJS</title>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()">
    Nome<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.nome"><br>
    Email<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.email"><br>
    Senha<br>
    <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.senha"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        $scope.status = null;
        $scope.msg = null;
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.$watch('user', function (newValue, oldValue) {
             if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                 $scope.post(newValue);
             }
        });

        $scope.post = function (user) {
            try {

                $http({
                    url: "php/salvar.php",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {'user': user}

                }).success(function (response) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(response.status)) {
                         console.log(response.status);
                        $scope.status = response.status;
                         console.log(response.msg);
                        $scope.msg = response.msg;
                    }

                });

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

        };

}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

E no PHP, eu não lembro se é array ou objeto, eu tratei para os dois casos, mas você pode dar um `var_dump($_POST); die();` para ver a saída, mas creio que seja algo como isso:

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'angularDB';
$host = 'localhost';

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

 $user = $_POST['user'];

if (is_array( $user)) {
 $nome = $user['nome']; 
 $email = $user['email'];
 $senha = $user['senha'];
} else {
 $nome = $user->nome; 
 $email = $user->email;
 $senha = $user->senha;
}

 $ins = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, '$nome', '$email', '$senha')");

if ($ins) {
    json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!'));
} else {
   echo json_encode( array('status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Erro ao cadastrar no banco.'));
}
?>
```

Comment: Só uma coisa @IvanFerrer, seu eu rodar só o php, a variável user virá vazia.
E se eu rodar com o HTML, não aparecerá o resultado do var_dump, você ta sabendo disso, né?

Comment: Seu código HTML, parece que nem submeter os dados não submeteu, pois não apareceu nada no console.

Comment: Claro que aparece @GustavoSevero, é só você executar no console do Chrome, na aba network, selecione a opção All e clique o arquivo executado, vai aparecer o array.

Comment: Se achar complicado pode utilizar algum site tipo esse: http://resttesttest.com/

Comment: Ou essa extensão do chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo